# multiple changes to a table with one checkbox selection - changing class of one td and style of parent tr using id and class

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change the third `td` based on class type of "price" while using the same checkbox to change the parent `tr` to show from hidden.
Pretty sure the `addClass` and `removeClass` are not used right here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function()
    {
        var divId = $(this).attr("id");

        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("." + divId).show();
            $("." + addClass).countable();
        }
        else {
            $("." + divId).hide();
            $("." + removeClass).countable();
        }

    });
});
```

Here is the checkbox:

```
<input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" value="42"> example<br/>
<input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" value="43"> example<br/>
```

Here is a segment of the table Im trying to update:

```
</tr><tr class="42" style="display:none">
<td>example</td>
<td></td>
<td></td><td class="price">7800</td></tr><tr class="43" style="display:none">
<td>First Area</td>
<td></td>
<td></td><td class="price">6900</td></tr>
```

Any help is much appreciated and thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to use the input's value to generate a class selector but you're using the input's ID instead, also, `addClass` and `removeClass` are functions that you call on a `jQuery` object. Here is an example with what I think you're trying to do:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");

    var $trElement = $('.' + val);
    var $tdPriceElement = $trElement.find('td.price');
    
    $trElement.toggle(isChecked);
    $tdPriceElement.toggleClass('countable', isChecked);
  });
});
```

```css
.countable {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" value="42"/> example<br/>
<input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" value="43"/> example<br/>

<table>
<tr class="42" style="display:none">
  <td>example</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td class="price">7800</td>
</tr>
<tr class="43" style="display:none">
  <td>First Area</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td class="price">6900</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The [`.toggle(...)`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function shows/hides the element based on the boolean value passed as a parameter, the [`.toggleClass(..)`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function adds/removes a class name based on the boolean value passed as the second parameter.

As @zfrisch mentioned, since it seems that each row has its own class name (42, 43, ...), you should probably use IDs instead.

Comment: that works for updating the whole `tr` to add the countable class. What I'm attempting to do is change the `tr` to show but also change the td `class="price"` to `class="countable"` or to add the class of countable to the existing class. in one action.

Comment: Nice answer. I'd +1 it again if I could for going the route of code clarity instead of minimalism. I know it's OP's markup you're going off of, but just to steer some people in the future: If you're trying to grab singular elements as OP is trying to do ("42", "43")  it's best to use an **ID** and *not* a **class**. Classes are supposed to be applied to a generalized group, ID's are specific.

Comment: @Titus That works exactly as I was looking. Just for my reference what would be the edit to allow for that to replace price class then change back to price?

Comment: @speshock To do that, you'll need a different selector to get a reference to the cell, instead of `td.price` you'll have to use something like `td:eq(3)` which will select the 4th `td` element and replace `$tdPriceElement.toggleClass('countable', isChecked);` with `$tdPriceElement.toggleClass('price', isChecked);`

Comment: @Titus Thanks for that. It solves the extra steps I was working on and works both inside the element and a print to pdf applicaiton on both windows chrome and iPad chrome.